# mongodb query not working with a collection in Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
mongoexport --host xxxg1a.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username xxxx --password xxxxx --authenticationDatabase admin --db Bigdatabase --collection Syallabus --query='{"CourseID":{$gte":3}}'  --out Logs.json
2020-01-10T12:49:05.818-0600    WARNING: ignoring unsupported URI parameter 'replicaset'
2020-01-10T12:49:05.819-0600    query '[39 123 67 111 117 114 115 101 73 68 58 123 36 103 116 101 58 51 125 125 39 32 32 45 45 111 117 116 32 67 58 92 85 115 101 114 115 92 115 97 100 97 115 105 118 97 92 68 101 115 107 116 111 112 92 115 104 105 118 97 45 97 114 99 111 114 101 92 70 105 110 97 108 83 99 104 101 109 97 115 92 65 73 65 76 111 103 115 46 106 115 111 110]' is not valid JSON: invalid character '-' after top-level value
2020-01-10T12:49:05.821-0600    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

I am having CourseID which is Syallabus with values 1,2,3,4. I want the outputjson with only 3 and 4.
I keeping getting this Error? is there any issue with the query.

I tried `{"CourseID":3}` to explicitly get only with 3. even than its notw orking.

```
2020-01-10T13:45:44.229-0600    WARNING: ignoring unsupported URI parameter 'replicaset'
2020-01-10T13:45:44.229-0600    query '[39 123 67 111 117 114 115 101 73 68 58 51 125 39]' is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
2020-01-10T13:45:44.231-0600    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. as its windows we should keep \ in query